# Cannot Import Model Name Django with User Model and Informational Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x105de5048>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/Name/Desktop/ProjectDevCode/Restructured/mysite/seasons/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from users.models import User
  File "/Users/Name/Desktop/ProjectDevCode/Restructured/mysite/users/models.py", line 11, in <module>
    from seasons.models import Seasons
ImportError: cannot import name 'Seasons'
```

I randomly got this error in my recent django app. I am not sure why. The models import in other apps/files in my project. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add your code where you import and project structure

Comment: is `seasons` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`?

Comment: @py_dude it turned out to be a circular model import. Check below for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you faced circular model import. Seems like you are importing User into seasons.model and Seasons into users.model.

If you use them as a foreign key you can set it as:

```
user = models.ForeignKey('users.User')
```

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated.

Comment: If it helped, could you mark my answer as a solution? Good luck!